# Obtener href con selector CSS en JS

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy intentando obtener en JS el contenido del atributo `href` de una etiqueta `a` que contiene un `img` que tengo identificado a través de un `#id`.

Me gustaría obtener la lista de parámetros del enlace y estoy probando con

```
document.querySelector('a>#prueba')['href']
```

Pero no estoy convencido de que sea posible, por muchas vueltas que le dé al CSS.

Me gustaría obtener el contenido del etiqueta `href`:

```
enlace?campo1=dato1&campo2=dato2
```

O, incluso aún mejor, un array asociativo con los campos y sus datos.

Adjunto un ejemplo simplificado del problema por si alguien que tenga frescos los selectores CSS recuerda cómo conseguirlo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test(id){
    console.log(document.getElementById(id)['src']);
    console.log(document.querySelector('a>#prueba')['href']);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <a></a><a></a><a></a> ... <a></a>
    <a href="enlace?campo1=dato1&campo2=dato2"><img src="foco_ok.png" 
        id="prueba"
        onclick="test('prueba');return false;"
    ></a>
</div>
</html>
```

Cualquier comentario para modernizar un poco el código será bien recibido, así como cualquier otra solución que obtenga el dato con selectores de JS en vez de CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que sería mas facil obtener el contenido que deseas con el método `getAttribute()` pasando como argumento el valor que deseas retornar

Ejemplo

- Obtienes el enlace por medio de su etiqueta con `document.querySelector()`
- A esa variable le asignas que acceda al método `getAttribute`
- Al método `getAttribute` le pasas como argumento entre comillas el valor que en este caso sería `href`

Quedando así:

```
let contenido = document.querySelector("a")
console.log(contenido.getAttribute("href"))
```

Dando como salida:

> "enlace?campo1=dato1&campo2=dato2"

Si tienes múltiples etiquetas a, de las cuales quieres obtener el valor de su atributo `href` usa `querySelectorAll()` el cual devuelve todos los elementos que coincidan con un parámetro dado.

Posterior puedes acceder a dicho atributo por medio de un ciclo `forEach`

```html
    <div>
        <a href="enlace?campo1=dato1&campo2=dato2">
        <a href="enlace?campo3=dato3&campo3=dato3">
        <a href="enlace?campo4=dato4&campo4=dato4">
          <img src="foco_ok.png">
      </a>
      <div class="contenido"></div>
    <script>
        let contenido = document.querySelectorAll("a")
        let imagen = document.querySelector("img")
        
        contenido.forEach((elemento) => {
          console.log(elemento.getAttribute("href"))
        })
        
    </script>
```

**Ejemplo final**

Considerando que podemos querer ver el contenido del atributo `href` de todos los enlaces o solo de uno en específico, compuse este pequeño script

```
<div>
    <a href="enlace?campo1=dato1&campo2=dato2">
    <a href="enlace?campo3=dato3&campo3=dato3">
    <a href="enlace?campo4=dato4&campo4=dato4">
      <img src="foco_ok.png">
  </a>
  <div class="contenido"></div>
<script>
    let contenido = document.querySelectorAll("a")
    let imagen = document.querySelector("img")


      let eleccion = prompt("Teclea 1 si deseas ver todos los valores o 2 para elegir un enlace")
      if (eleccion == 1) {
        contenido.forEach((elemento) => {
          console.log(elemento.getAttribute("href"))
        })
      } else if(eleccion == 2) {
        let valorUnico = prompt("Que enlace deseas ver? del 1 al 3?")
        if (valorUnico == 1) {
          console.log(contenido[0].getAttribute("href"))
        } else if(valorUnico == 2) {
          console.log(contenido[1].getAttribute("href"))
        } else {
          console.log(contenido[2].getAttribute("href"))
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Opción no válida")
      }
</script>
```

**Referencia**

- [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: Ok, me has pillado, en el ejemplo sólo tengo una `a` y la localizas sin problema :) ... En el caso real tengo un número indeterminado de enlaces, ¿hay forma de localizar esa `a` con la ayuda del #id del `img` o le pongo un `id` propio y resuelto?

Comment: @DavidJP ok dame un momento

Comment: Genial, edito la pregunta y así ya queda coherente con tu respuesta...

Answer (score 3):

No estás poniendo bien el `id` al elemento. Tal y como lo tienes ahora ese `id` lo adquiere el elemento `src`, no el elemento `a`.

También te recomendaría evitar el uso de funciones *in line*. Se consideran una mala práctica porque no respetan el principio de separación del código. Una función *in line*  es poner parte del código Javascript en el HTML. Si esa función debiera cambiar de nombre o recibir otros parámetros y tuvieras 5,000 archivos HTML que la usen, vas a tener que abrir y modificar esos 5,000 archivos.

En este ejemplo pasamos la función al código JS. Para crear de forma transparente y elegante un objeto con los parámetros de la URL usaremos [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) combinado con [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/fromEntries)

Si no te interesa este estilo, ten en cuenta que sobre un `href` puedes aplicar `search` también para obtener únicamente la parte del query string y crear tu objeto por el método antiguo, haciendo `split` o lo que sea.

```js
//Referencia al elemento
var elAnchor = document.querySelector('#prueba');

//Asignamos listener al elemento
elAnchor.addEventListener("click", test, false);

//La función
function test(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var mParams = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(elAnchor.search));
  console.log(mParams);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="prueba" href="enlace?campo1=dato1&campo2=dato2"><img src="foco_ok.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: La dificultad estaba precisamente en que el #id estuviera en el `img` y no en el `a`, en cómo acceder a atributos de la etiqueta que contenía el elemento identificado. Genial la aportación del `addEventListener` para evitar código inline y el `URLSearchParams` para extraer los parámetros, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: @DavidJP ¿quieres decir con la primera parte del comentario que el `id` debe estar sí o sí en el elemento `img`? ¿Por qué debería estar ahí y no en el anchor tag? A mi juicio es una especie de lógica inversa, generalmente se identifican los elementos de nivel superior y a través de ellos puedes alcanzar a los elementos de nivel inferior que se encuentran dentro de ellos. En este caso `a` es superior a `img` y por medio de `a` puedes alcanzar a `img` si hiciera falta.

Comment: Realmente ha sido por curiosidad. En este caso puedo poner el #id en el `a`, pero lo había puesto anteriormente en el `img` para otra cosa y trataba de intentar obtener el dato en el orden inverso por no cambiarlo de sitio o tener que añadir otro id. Pregunté para situaciones en las que no se puede tocar el HTML... En este caso, afortunadamente, tengo control del código y puedo resolverlo sin tanta complicación. En cualquier caso, se agradece tu simplificación, a veces nos complicamos innecesariamente y no vemos la forma fácil y directa...

Comment: @DavidJP los selectores son una herramienta riquísima para alcanzar los elementos en situaciones verdaderamente complicadas. Ahora bien, mientras más simple y conforme a las buenas prácticas ordenes los elementos, más fácil será todo. Me alegro de que te haya servido.